# How to extract only non-zero values from an array and put them into a cell

Tags: matlab

I have:

```
X6 =

  Columns 1 through 18
 5     3     5     5     4     1     4     4     2     4     4     4     4     4     4     5     5     4
 5     4     4     3     3     4     5     2     4     5     2     4     4     4     4     5     4     5
 5     2     4     4     2     3     3     3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 2     3     3     3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 4     5     3     3     2     3     3     3     3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 3     2     4     2     3     3     5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 2     4     4     5     4     5     5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 4     2     5     5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

  Columns 19 through 27 

     4     5     4     4     4     4     3     3     4
     3     3     4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I'd like to make a cell `X6cell` which takes non-zero `X6` values row by row.

So `X6cell{1}={1x27}, X6cell{8}={1x4}` etc...

```
for i=1:size(X6,1)
X6cell{i}=X6(X6(i,:)~=isnan);
end
```

is not quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. The syntax is:

```
for i=1:size(X6,1)
    X6cell{i}=X6(i,~isnan(X6(i,:)));
end
```

(One alternative: you can also use `isfinite(X6(i,:))` if you also want to ignore any Inf values as well as NaNs, which can be useful at times)

To remove zeros (or any individual number):

```
for i=1:size(X6,1)
    X6cell{i}=X6(i,X6(i,:)~=0);
end
```

To remove any amount of numbers, use `~ismember`:

```
discard_values=[1 5 7 20 100];
for i=1:size(X6,1)
    X6cell{i}=X6(i,~ismember(X6(i,:),discard_values));
end
```

To chain these rules (introducing a new variable just for clarity), use `&`:

```
discard_values=[1 5 7 20 100];
for i=1:size(X6,1)
    indices_to_keep= ~ismember(X6(i,:),discard_values) & ~isnan(X6(i,:));
    X6cell{i}=X6(i,indices_to_keep);
end
```